# Point of intersection of two lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to work out where two lines would intersect each other. I have two sets of co-ordinates to draw two lines.
Line 1:
x=-493, y=706  &  x=-618, y=886

Line 2:
x=-965, y=372  &  x=-865, y=572

However the line intersecting with Line 1 one is actually Line 3
All that I know about line 3 is that it is exactly in the middle of line 2 and at 90 degrees to this line.

At which point will Line 1 & Line 3 intersect?

Please if you could show calculations as well, this would really help me a lot as I am now beyond confused.

Comment: The part " line 3 is that it is exactly in the middle of line 2 " should be replaced by "line 3 is the perpendicular bissector of the segment determined by points $A(-965, 372)$ & $B(-865,572)$" ; it's confusing to speak about line 2. Hint : determine the midpoint C of [AB] then find an equation y=mx+b for the perpendicular bissector (B) by forcing $C$ to belong to (B) then express that one of its points e.g., (0,b) is at the same distance from A and from B...

Comment: Thanks Jean but I actually have no idea how to even calculate or to use the formula y=mx+b.

What I think I have worked out, but I'm not entirely sure is that C would be (-915, 472)

But then what?

Comment: Then... do you agree that the equation of a straight line is y=ax+b at least (y=2x+1, or y=-x+5? It means you have 2 constants a and b to find. Thus you have 2 constraints to find (you know that : 2 equations with two unknowns gives - in general - "the" solution). 1st constraint : the equation must be fulfilled if x=-915, then y=472. How do write this constraint ?

Comment: I haven't used Algebra in 16 years so I am completely lost.

Comment: For A & B m would be equal to -1.448. I did this by saying m = (y2-y1) / (x2 - x1)

Comment: The constraint is that equation $y=ax+b$ is to be verified by point C. Thus $472=a(-915)+b$. This is the first equation linking unknowns $a$ and $b$. Then the second. Let D(0,b) (length DA^2)=(length DB^2) gives $(0--965)^2+(b-372)^2=(0--865)^2+(b-572)^2$ which will give you an equation in $b$ only.

Comment: I see you follow a different path; then take the following reasonning : the slope of a line perp. to a line which has a slop $m$ has a slope $a=-1/m$. Good luck for the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43666/discussion-between-leon-claassen-and-jeanmarie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step away from book definitions and formulas and rules and let's *think*.

A line has a slope, $m$, which measures how much the line raises vertically for every unit it runs horizontally.  It is literally the ratio of the rise over the run.  If it raises sharply it has a large slope if raises slowly it has a small slope.  If it "goes downhill" it has a negative slope.

And to figure the slope, which is *literally* the rise over the run we calculate how much the the $y$ value of a line changes, divided by how much the $x$ value changes.

So $l_1$ as the points:x=-493, y=706 and  x=-618, y=886.  So the $y$ values changes: $(886 - 706) = 180$ and the $x$ value changes: (-618 - (-493)) = -125.  So the slope: $m_1 = 180/-125 = - 36/25$.  So line 1 is a line that decreases fairly sharply; for every 25 units horizontally, it decreases 36 units vertically.

And $l_2$ has the points:  x=-965, y=372 and  x=-865, y=572.  So the $y$ value changes $(572 - 372) = 200$ and the $x$ value changes $-865 - (-965) = 100$. So the slope is $m_2 = 200/100 =2$.  This is a very steep line that raises 2 units vertically for every one unit horizontally.

Note as these two lines have different slopes one raises more sharply than the other.  So they must intersect.  If they had the same slope they would never intersect and they'd be parallel but they have different slopes so they must intersect.

So how do we write a formula for a line if we know the slope?  Well, we also need at least one point.  Let's take $l_1$ that has the point: x = -493 and y= 706. So what if picked another point on the line $x, y$.

How much have we moved horizontally?  Well, we've moved from $-493$ to $x$ so that's a difference of $x - (-493) = x + 493$.

How much have we moved vertically?  Well, we've mover from $706$ to $y$ so that's a difference of $y - 706$.

How is $x$ related to y$.  Well, remember the slope is the rise over the run so:

$m_1 = -36/25 = (y-706)/(x + 493$. and that is the equation of $l_1$: $(y- 706)/(x + 493) = -36/25$.  For any point on $l_1$ the x, y values satisfy this equation.

But it's are to use in that form.  Better is $y - 706 = (-36/25)(x + 493)$.  Or in general $y - y_1 = m_1(x - x_1$ where ($x_1, y_1$) is one of the points.

Notice if your initial point was $x = 0$ and $y = b$ (this is called that $y$-intercept as it crosses the $y$-axis at $x = 0$) then this formula became $y - b = m_1(x - 0) \implies y = m_1x + b$, which is the formula from all the books.

But we don't *have* to start at $x = 0; y = b$ we can start at any point.

The formula for $l_2$ is therefore $y - 372 = m_2(x - (-965)) \implies y = 2(x + 965)$.

Okay.  Take a breather...

=====

So we aren't given anything about $l_3$ except:

1) It is perpendicular to $l_2$.

Well what does that mean?  Well, if $l_2$ goes up then $l_3$ goes down (and vice versa).  So the two slopes will have opposite signs.  $m_2$ is positive so $m_3$ is negative.

Perpendicular slopes have opposite signs.

If $l_2$ goes horizontally A units and vertically B units.  Then the perpendicular line will go over horizontally B units and down A units.  Maybe you should draw some pictures to convince yourself of this.  But perpendicular leans are twistin the line 90 degress so what was sideways is now down and what was up, is not sideways.

So $m_2 = rise_2/run_2$ and $m_3 = -(run_2/rise_2)$.  In other words: If $l_3$ is perpendicular to $l_2$ then $m_3 = -1/m_2 = - 1/2$.

2) we know that $l_3$ is "cuts the line segment between x=-965, y=372 and x=-865, y=572 in half".

So it contains x = halfway between -965 and -865, and y = halfway between 372 and 572.  So it contains $x = \frac {-965 +(-865)}2 = \frac {-1830}2 = -915$ and $y = \frac {372 + 572}2 = 472$.

So $m_3 = - 1/2$ and $l_3$ has the point $x = -915; y = 472$.  So the formula is:

$(y - 472)/(x + 915) = - 1/2 \implies y - 472 = - 1/2(x + 915)$.

Okay, take another breather.  You've earned it.

====

So $m_3 = -1/2$ and $m_1 = -36/25$ are different so the lines are not parallel so they intersect at one point.  Which one.

Well call it $(x, y)$.  It's on $l_1$ so $y - 706 = (-36/25)(x + 493)$.

It's also  on $l_3$ so $y - 472 = - 1/2(x + 915)$.

What $x, y$ are both of those true.

Well  $y - 472 = - 1/2(x + 915)$ so

$y - 472 = -1/2 x + 467.5$

$y = -1/2 x + 467.5 + 472 = -(1/2)x +932.5$.

But also $y - 706 = (-36/25)(x + 493)$

So $((-1/2)x + 932.5) - 706 = (-36/25)(x + 493)$

So $(-1/2)x - 126.5= -(36/25)x - 702.92$

So $(36/25 - 1/2)x = 126.5 - 702.92$

So $(22/25)x = -576.42$

So $x = -576.42*25/22 = -655 1/44$

So that is $x$.  What is $y$?

$y = -(1/2)x +932.5 = -(1/2)(-655 1/44) + 932.5 = 1260 1/88$

.....

which... I can't believe I didn't make an arithmetical error.  So you will have proof read my actual numbers.

=====

Post script: Those numbers were bulky and got in the way of comprehension.

Here's more example with easier numbers.

Line 1: has points (1,5) and (4,11).  [That is $x =1;y = 5$ and $x = 4; y = 11$.]

Then $m_1 = $ slope = $rise/run = (11 -5)/(4-1) = 6/3 = 2$.

So $L_1$ contains all the points where: $(y-5)/(x - 1) = 2$ or $y-5 = 2(x -1)$.

So, for example the following points are on the line: (2,7), (3,9), (1,5), (7.5,18) etc as they all fit the formula.

Note: we could have used the other point (or any) point to get:

$(y-11)/(x-4) = 2$ so $y-11 = 2(x-4)$.  These describe the exact same points.

To make the equation easier to use we can expand:

$y-5 = 2(x -1)\implies  y - 5 = 2x - 2 \implies y = 2x - 2 + 5 = 2x + 3$

likewise the other equation:

$y-11 = 2(x-4) \implies y - 11 = 2x - 8 \implies y = 2x - 8 + 11 = 2x + 3$

Gives the exact same result.

we can plug in any value of $x$ and get out the exact values of $y$ with this.

$x = -3,-2,-1,0,1, 2, 3$ then $y = -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10$ for the points (-3,-3), (-2,-1),(-1,1)(0,3),(1,5), (2, 7),(3,10) etc.

[If $x = 6/5$ then $y = 12/5 + 3 = 27/5$ so $(6/5, 27/5)$ is a point on this line. What a weird point to check!]

If $x = 0$ then $y = 3$ so $(0,3)$ is what is called the $y$-intercept (where $x=0$ a any $y$ is the number where the line "intercepts" the y-axis) and this gives us the standard $(y-3)/(x - 0) = 2 \implies y-3 = 2(x-0) \implies y = 2x + 3$ which yields the familiar $y = mx + b$ form.

We can also "solve for x" to get $y = 2x + 3 \implies y - 3 = 2x \implies (y-3)/2 = x \implies x = \frac 1/2y - \frac 32$.  This is the less familier equation $x = \frac 1m + a$ where $a = -b/m =$ the $x$ intercept.  This is where $y = 0 and $x = a = -b/m$.  It's where the line intercepts the $x$-axis.

We can plug in $y = -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ to get $x = -2,-1 1/2, -1, - 1/2, 0, 1/2, 2, 2 1/2, 3$.

So Line 2: has points $(0, -1)$ and $(6,1)$.

$m_2 = (1-(-1))/(6-0) = 2/6 = 1/3.

The equation is $(y +1)/(x - 0) = 1/3 \implies y+2 = \frac 13 x \implies y = \frac 13 -2$.

Line 1 and Line 2 intersect at the point where:

$y = 2x + 3$  and $y = \frac 13x  - 2$

So $2x + 3 = \frac 13x - 2$

So $1 2/3*x = 5/3 * x = - 5$

So $x = -5*3/5 = -3$

$y = 2(-3) + 3 = -3$

(we can also check $y = 1/3(-3) - 2 = -3$.)

So the lines intersect at $(-3, -3)$; the one point on both lines.

Line three is perpendicular to line 2, and intersects at the mid-point of segment $(0, -1)$ and $(6,1)$.

So $m_3 = - 1/m_2 = -1/(1/3) = -3$

The midpoint of $(0,-1)$ and $(6,1)$ is $((6+0)/2, (1+(-1))/2) = (3, 0)$.

So the equation for $L_3$ is $(y - 0)/(x -3) = -3 \implies y = -3(x-3) = -3x+9$.

So points on this line $(-1, 12), (0, 9), (1, 6), (6/5,  27/5),(2, 3)$ etc.  [(6/5, 27/5)?  What a strange point to check.]

So L_3 and L_1 intersect when

$y = 2x + 3$ and $y = -3x + 9$

So $2x + 3 = -3x + 9 \implies 5x = 6 \implies x = 6/5$.

So $y = 2(6/5) + 3$ which should equal $-3(6/5) + 9$

So $y = 12/5 + 15/5 = 27/5$ which does equal $-18/5 + 45/5 = 27/5$.

So Line 1 and Line 3 intersect at $(6/5, 275)$.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this... This really makes a lot more sense than trying to go through the previous answers. Adding numbers in really create more perspective.

What I'd like to is in almost the very last step you have -576*25/22 = -6551/44. I'm just a little confused how you got to -6551/44.

Comment: Punched it into a calculator and get repeating decimal. And got -576.42 * 25/22 = 655.02272727272727272727272727273 = 655 1/44.  Honestly though.  I'm almost certain that I've made arithmetic error somewhere as that number is just too awkward.  This is a difficult problem in that the numbers are very "bulky" and unweildy and doing the arithmetic is very distracting.  It'd have been a lot easy to write this as a lesson with "nicer" numbers.

Comment: @fleablood With all the respect I have for your dedication to this issue, I confirm that it is my results which are the good ones (I have checked with the formula given by Futurologist).

Comment: I don't doubt that your result are the good ones.  And if you've confirmed them they must be true.  I'm not sure where I made an error but it could be something as assinine and frustrating as subtracting as failing to carry a 1.

Comment: " I confirm that it is my results which are the good ones"  I'm a bit perplexed as to why you keep pointing this out.

Comment: I am very sorry if you have taken this as a critic. The purpose was only in fact to say to the OP : take care, if you want only the final result, this one is the good result. But, we know all that the result is far less important, in particular for somebody who wants to understand like Leon Claassen, than the methodology to be used. And, once again, I have admired your step by step, very patient, methodology, and your dedication.

Comment: Now, I'm not sure where my error is but math errors happen all the time.

Answer (score 1):

A general method: let $A=(A_1, A_2)^T, \, B=(B_1, B_2)^T, C=(C_1, C_2)^T$ and $D=(D_1, D_2)^T$ be four points and we want to find where the line orthogonal to and passing through the midpoint of the segment $AB$ intersects the line $CD$. We write the orthogonal line in the form $$ (B-A)^T\left(x-\frac{1}{2}(A+B)\right) =0$$ and the line $CD$ in the form
$$ x = C+t(D-C) $$
where $x=(x_1,x_2)^T$ is a point. Then the intersection point $x$ satisfies both equations so we plug the  second expression for $x$ into the first one in order to find the parameter $t$:
$$ (B-A)^T\left(C+t(D-C) - \frac{1}{2}(A+B)\right) =0$$ and we solve for $t$:
$$t_0= \frac{\frac{1}{2}(B-A)^T(A+B)-(B-A)^TC}{(B-A)^T(D-C)}.$$ Then the intersection point is expressed as
$$x=C+ \frac{\frac{1}{2}(B-A)^T(A+B)-(B-A)^TC}{(B-A)^T(D-C)}(D-C).$$ The symbol $T$ as a superscript in some expressions means vector (matrix) transposition. All vectors are vector columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I honestly have absolutely no clue what you are talking about. Please remember that the last time I did any form of Algebra was 16 years ago. I have managed to work out what I think are the two different line slopes, but even this I don't know if its correct.

Comment: Do bear in mind that the OP has clearly never study linear algebra and all and last took high school algebra 16 years ago.

Comment: Your formula is exact. I have checked my results against it (-921/47,1142/47). The only thing I had to adapt is that letters $A$ and $B$ are to be interchanged with letters $C$ and $D$ resp.

Comment: Thanks for comparing with your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

@fleablood I have made the calculations and, unless I have made an error, I find different values than yours for the intersection point, i.e.,

$$(-921/47 , 1142/47) = (-19.5957 , 24.2979)$$

See graphics below.

Here is how I have obtained it.

1) I have expressed line $\ell_1$ under the so convenient parametric form:

$$x = -493 - 125t; y = 706 + 180t \ \ (1)$$

2) I have expressed that among all these points, say $M$, I desire the (unique) point at the same distance from $A$ and $B$, under the form of equality $MA^2=MB^2$, i.e.,

$$(x + 965)^2 + (y - 372)^2 = (x + 865)^2 + (y - 572)^2 \ \ (2)$$

3) I then plug in (2) expressions from (1). With some patience (and hopefully a symbolic computation tool), you get:

$$1000 (178+47t)=0$$

Thus the convenient value is $t=-178/47$.

4) It suffices now to replace $t$ by this value in (1)...

[image]

Comment: @fleablood I have provided explanations.

Comment: I have no doubt I made an error (unless the problem writer did).  One doesn't make effort to have numbers exactly 200, 300, 180, and 125 units apart only to have the final answer involve huge numbers divided by 11.  I'm sure your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped on this. I managed to finally get the desired solution. And got a lot better understanding of getting there thanks to everyone's inputs.